# Question about msg.value

Tags: contract-development

```
uint256 amount = msg.value;
```

this means if use my code

```
var tx = await tronweb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx('TKKtaGBH2E2nGSK7F6zKUxvrvtr6iRbp1S', 10 * 1e6, window.tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58)
```

that means I will get 10 value from msg.value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.value` is the transaction value in [Wei](https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-are-the-different-units-used-in-ethereum), not the equivalent amount in Ether. If you send 1 Ether (= 10^18 Wei), `msg.value` will be 10^18.